# How to install pip3 without upgrading Python version?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux

I'm trying to install software in kali that requires my Python version to be 3.6.9 or lower.
I also need to install pip to install requirements.
I have Python3.6.9 installed and when I run `#apt-get install python3-pip`
It also updates my Python version to 3.10
Is there a way to get pip installed without upgrading my python version?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to install `pip` on to an existing python installation, which did not come with pip pre-installed, you can use the bootstrap script to that.
Like

```
curl -sSL https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python get-pip.py  #or python3
```

If you want to update the pip version installed, then you can use

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```